# Storing text from file to array

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have a text file which looks like this

```
{{"12","13","2","5"},
 {"14","14","1","4"},
 {"36","30","1","9"}}
```

And I want to  Store this in the array
the size of the array from the above same file is 3x4
where each row of the file has 4 string and there are 3 such row
so the array should look like

```
array[0][1]="12"
array[0][2]="13"
array[0][3]="2"
array[0][4]="5"
array[1][1]="14"
array[1][2]="14"
array[1][3]="1"
array[1][4]="4"
array[2][1]="36"
array[2][2]="30"
array[2][3]="1"
array[2][4]="9"
```

any algorithm, implantation, suggestion will be appliciated

Comment: Looks like JSON data, is it?

Comment: Yes it is Kind of Json but It is the output That i got from another software and now I want to store them in array for further processing

Comment: @BoristheSpider this is no valid json. For correct json, the curly-brackets must be replaced by square brackets as the values have no assosiated keys.

Comment: yes it is not JSON format the problem is how can I extract the values as the do not have uniform Curly Brackets to use Split method or Delimiter

Comment: Does your file always have one row in one line? Do you know how many lines will there be in file? Can you maybe use collections (lists) instead of arrays?

Comment: @danijoo very good point.

Comment: Yes my file always have one row in one line. Yes before hand I know how many line are going to be there in the file.The basic thing I want to do is to extract the data by using array or any class from collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this very easily with `replaceAll` and `split` like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String input = "{{\"12\",\"13\",\"2\",\"5\"},{\"14\",\"14\",\"1\",\"4\"},{\"36\",\"30\",\"1\",\"9\"}}";
    final String[] rows = input.replaceAll("^\\{\\{|}}$", "").split("},\\{");
    final String[][] transformed = new String[rows.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
        final String[] columns = rows[i].replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "").split("\",\"");
        transformed[i] = new String[columns.length];
        System.arraycopy(columns, 0, transformed[i], 0, columns.length);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(transformed));
}
```

Output:

```
[[12, 13, 2, 5], [14, 14, 1, 4], [36, 30, 1, 9]]
```

If you use a `List<List<String>>` then it looks more like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String input = "{{\"12\",\"13\",\"2\",\"5\"},{\"14\",\"14\",\"1\",\"4\"},{\"36\",\"30\",\"1\",\"9\"}}";
    final String[] rows = input.replaceAll("^\\{\\{|}}$", "").split("},\\{");
    final List<List<String>> transformed = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final String row : rows) {
        final String[] columns = row.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "").split("\",\"");
        final List<String> transformedRow = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final String data : columns) {
            transformedRow.add(data);
        }
        transformed.add(transformedRow);
    }
}
```

Fewer loops by index make the code a little clearer, but it's really the `String` processing that's the painful part so you don't gain much.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that each line can contain only one row in one of form s

- `{{"a","b","c"},`
- `{"a","b","c"},`
- `{"a","b","c"}}`

In other words each line can start with `{{` or  `{` and end with `},` or `},`.

What you need to do is

1. read file line by line,
2. remove all of `{` and `}` and quotation mark at start and end so you will get only `a","b","c`
3. split result on `","` to get array `[a,b,c]`
4. place that array in your result array

Your code can look like (instead of String with data from file you can use File which represents location of your file):

```
int rows = 3;
String[][] result = new String[rows][];

String data = "{{\"12\",\"13\",\"2\",\"5\"},\r\n"
        + " {\"14\",\"14\",\"1\",\"4\"},\r\n"
        + " {\"36\",\"30\",\"1\",\"9\"}}";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(data);

for (int i=0; i<rows; i++){
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    line = line.replaceAll("[\\s{]\\{\"|\"\\}[,}]", "");
    result[i]=line.split("\",\"");
}
sc.close();

for (String[] arr : result)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output:

```
[12, 13, 2, 5]
[14, 14, 1, 4]
[36, 30, 1, 9]
```

---

If you are using Java 8 you can also use streams

```
List<String[]> rows = Files.lines(Paths.get("input.txt"))
    .map(s -> s.replaceAll("[\\s{]\\{\"|\"\\}[,}]", ""))
    .map(s-> s.split("\",\""))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Function<String, String[]> breakIntoArray = (String s)->{
        s = s.replaceAll("}", "");
        s = s.replaceAll("\\{", "");
        s = s.replaceAll("\"", "");
        return s.split(",");
    };

    Path tradePath = Paths.get("xxx.txt");
    Files.lines(tradePath).map(breakIntoArray).collect(Collectors.toList());
```